# Error BasicErrorController due annotation @EnableAspectJAutoProxy in Spring Boot 2.3.6

Tags: spring-boot, maven, aspectj, spring-aop, spring-aspects

I'm doing migration small own library from java 8 and Spring Boot 1.5.x to java 11 and Spring Boot 2.3.x.
I have some tests in code. And when I run them in java 8, all is fine, all tests are passed.
But when I migrated to Java 11 and SB 2.3.x I got an error. This is log:

```
[INFO] -------------------< com.alexshuvaev.libs:log-aspects-library >-------------------
[INFO] Building log-aspects-library 1.0-SNAPSHOT                          [5/5]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.6:prepare-agent (default) @ log-aspects-library ---
[INFO] argLine set to -javaagent:C:\\Users\\Aleksandr_Shuvaev\\.m2\\repository\\org\\jacoco\\org.jacoco.agent\\0.8.6\\org.jacoco.agent-0.8.6-runtime.jar=destfile=D:\\projects\\alexshuvaev\\foraudit\\log-common\\log-aspects-library\\target\\jacoco.exec
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ log-aspects-library ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\projects\alexshuvaev\foraudit\log-common\log-aspects-library\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ log-aspects-library ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 11 source files to D:\projects\alexshuvaev\foraudit\log-common\log-aspects-library\target\classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ log-aspects-library ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ log-aspects-library ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 10 source files to D:\projects\alexshuvaev\foraudit\log-common\log-aspects-library\target\test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ log-aspects-library ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: D:\projects\alexshuvaev\foraudit\log-common\log-aspects-library\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.alexshuvaev.libs.logging.annotation.EnableLogAspectsImportSelectorTest
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.388 sec
Running com.alexshuvaev.libs.logging.annotation.LoggableContextTest
2021-02-13 14:36:35.552  INFO   --- [           main] .b.t.c.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper : Neither @ContextConfiguration nor @ContextHierarchy found for test class [com.alexshuvaev.libs.logging.annotation.LoggableContextTest], using SpringBootContextLoader
2021-02-13 14:36:35.566  INFO   --- [           main] o.s.t.c.support.AbstractContextLoader    : Could not detect default resource locations for test class [com.alexshuvaev.libs.logging.annotation.LoggableContextTest]: no resource found for suffixes {-context.xml, Context.groovy}.
2021-02-13 14:36:35.903  INFO   --- [           main] .b.t.c.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper : Loaded default TestExecutionListener class names from location [META-INF/spring.factories]: [org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.webservices.client.MockWebServiceServerTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.event.EventPublishingTestExecutionListener]
2021-02-13 14:36:35.928  INFO   --- [           main] .b.t.c.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper : Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@248ba4fc, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener@54cce500, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener@755033c5, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@229c4d34, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@5b49b1df, org.springframework.test.context.event.EventPublishingTestExecutionListener@689eab53, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener@1c24639e, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener@5c9168c3, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener@4ac0fdc7, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener@571903ff, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener@689ea211, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.webservices.client.MockWebServiceServerTestExecutionListener@3f1e18b1]

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.6.RELEASE)

2021-02-13 14:36:36.489  INFO 17272 --- [           main] r.v.d.l.annotation.LoggableContextTest   : Starting LoggableContextTest on EPRUKRAW003D with PID 17272 (started by Aleksandr_Shuvaev in D:\projects\alexshuvaev\foraudit\log-common\log-aspects-library)
2021-02-13 14:36:36.490 DEBUG 17272 --- [           main] r.v.d.l.annotation.LoggableContextTest   : Running with Spring Boot v2.3.6.RELEASE, Spring v5.2.11.RELEASE
2021-02-13 14:36:36.490  INFO 17272 --- [           main] r.v.d.l.annotation.LoggableContextTest   : The following profiles are active: test
2021-02-13 14:36:37.787  WARN 17272 --- [           main] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'TestsConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type name: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]
2021-02-13 14:36:37.809 ERROR 17272 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'TestsConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type name: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:405)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:123)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type name: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.parsePointcutExpression(PointcutParser.java:319)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.buildPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:227)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.obtainPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.getClassFilter(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:177)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:226)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:289)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AopUtils.java:321)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:128)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:78)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:347)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:430)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1798)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
    ... 47 common frames omitted
```

**Pom.xml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.alexshuvaev.libs</groupId>
        <artifactId>log-parent</artifactId>
        <relativePath>../log-parent</relativePath>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>log-aspects-library</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**Parent Pom.xml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>log-common</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.alexshuvaev.libs</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>log-parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <build.number>-1</build.number>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>

        <jacoco-plugin.version>0.8.6</jacoco-plugin.version>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.2.0</maven-jar-plugin.version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>

        <spring-boot.version>2.3.6.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
        <logback-more-appenders.version>1.8.4</logback-more-appenders.version>
        <fluent-logger.version>0.3.4</fluent-logger.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sndyuk</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-more-appenders</artifactId>
                <version>${logback-more-appenders.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.fluentd</groupId>
                <artifactId>fluent-logger</artifactId>
                <version>${fluent-logger.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>
                    <release>${java.version}</release>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring</arg>
                        <arg>-Amapstruct.unmappedTargetPolicy=WARN</arg>
                        <arg>-Amapstruct.suppressGeneratorTimestamp=true</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-jar-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                            <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Build-Number>${build.number}</Build-Number>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jacoco-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

In the code I have an annotation `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy`.
When I deleted, error is disappeared, but my tests not passing, because CGLIB fields are null. But must be like on this screenshot:

I tried to add BasicErrorController class in my code. Empty class with package: package org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web;
And then no errors, and all tests are passing. But I think it's not a good way.

Some more code:
In my main package:

```java
package com.alexshuvaev.libs.logging.annotation;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import com.alexshuvaev.libs.logging.aspects.OperType;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Import(EnableLogAspectsImportSelector.class)
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public @interface EnableLogAspects {
    OperType[] value() default {};
}
```

In my test package:

```java
package com.alexshuvaev.libs.logging;

import com.alexshuvaev.libs.logging.config.TestsConfiguration;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@ActiveProfiles("test")
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestsConfiguration.class)
public abstract class IntegrationTest {
}
```

```java
package com.alexshuvaev.libs.logging.config;

import com.alexshuvaev.libs.logging.IntegrationTest;
import com.alexshuvaev.libs.logging.annotation.EnableLogAspects;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;

@Configuration
@EnableLogAspects
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = IntegrationTest.class)
public class TestsConfiguration {

}
```

```java
package com.alexshuvaev.libs.logging.annotation;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import static com.alexshuvaev.libs.logging.aspects.OperType.LOGGABLE;
import static com.alexshuvaev.libs.logging.aspects.OperType.REST;

import com.alexshuvaev.libs.logging.IntegrationTest;
import com.alexshuvaev.libs.logging.aspects.LoggableAspect;
import com.alexshuvaev.libs.logging.aspects.OperType;
import com.alexshuvaev.libs.logging.testdata.SomeClassService;
import com.alexshuvaev.libs.logging.testdata.SomeController;
import com.alexshuvaev.libs.logging.testdata.SomeService;
import com.alexshuvaev.libs.logging.testdata.resource.SomeResource;
import com.alexshuvaev.libs.logging.utils.JoinPointLogUtils;

import ch.qos.logback.classic.Level;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent;
import ch.qos.logback.core.read.ListAppender;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

@Slf4j
public class LoggableContextTest extends IntegrationTest {

    private static ListAppender<ILoggingEvent> loggingAppender;

    @Before
    public void initAppender() {
        LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
        loggingAppender = new ListAppender<>();
        loggingAppender.setContext(context);
        loggingAppender.start();
        context.getLogger(SomeService.class).addAppender(loggingAppender);
        context.getLogger(SomeClassService.class).addAppender(loggingAppender);
        context.getLogger(SomeController.class).addAppender(loggingAppender);
        context.getLogger(SomeResource.class).addAppender(loggingAppender);
    }

    @After
    public void cleanAppender() {
        loggingAppender.list.clear();
    }

    @Autowired
    private SomeService someService;

    @Autowired
    private SomeClassService someClassService;

    @Autowired
    private SomeController someController;

    @Autowired
    private SomeResource someResource;


    @Test
    public void defaultTest() {
        someService.withDefaultVoid();
        assertAppenderSingleEvent(JoinPointLogUtils.END_EXECUTING_TEMPLATE_DETAILED_PARAMS, Level.DEBUG, SomeService.class);
    }
}
```

Why is `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` trying to find class `BasicErrorController` with a package from Spring Boot 1.5.x?
I cannot find dependencies incompatibility in my Pom.xml. May be I forgot to add any dependency?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Thanks for the interesting question and many details. I find it kind of funny though, that you have a problem related to Spring AOP but have to exclude your `LoggableAspect` source code from this question. Wouldn't you agree that the aspect is kind of crucial in this situation? BTW, given the many files it would also be helpful if you would share the whole project (or a minimal version of it reproducing the problem) on GitHub. This is called an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would greatly increase your chances of getting good answers quickly.

Comment: Friendly reminder: You still did not provide the aspect code. The question is almost answerable, but the aspect is still necessary because you are asking questions about it.